# Fastest way to read data separated by white space in Python

Tags: python, tabular

I have some data that is separated by white space from which I want to extract certain columns. In the past I have always used something like the following in Python, in which I have removed the non-essentials:

```
for line in open(f,'r'):
    l = line.split()
    print " ".join(l[1:3])
```

I'm wondering though whether this is the fastest way to do this. If I compare to another software package (written in C) that reads the same data, my code is significantly slower. Is this simply because I/O in C is faster or am I writing suboptimal code?

Comment: C is 10-100+ times faster then python in general so I doubt you can expect similar results.

Comment: Well you could be limiting the `split` if you're only using the first few items (`line.split(maxsplit=3)`).

Comment: Use a CSV library with space as the separator.

Comment: @marsh: The limiting factor in I/O is *always* network or disk speed, not cycles.

Comment: In general, unless the slowdown is a problem, it really doesn't matter anymore. Unless you are processing enormous amounts of data or doing enormous numbers of computations, CPU is not going to be your problem.

Comment: @Linuxios: Is there a CSV library that accepts any white space as separator? The data I work with is typically not that well-formed, with spaces and tabs both.

Comment: @niefpaarschoenen, if you have a mixture then the csv module won't work

Comment: @niefpaarschoenen: Python's CSV library seems to let you define your own CSV dialect class that could use both. Not sure though, I've never used it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected columns in a list using list comprehensions.

```
expectedColumns = [" ".join(x) for x in [line.split()[0:2] for line in file("testFile",'r').readlines()]]
```

If you want to print the columns inside LC, you can do this :)

```
from __future__ import print_function
[print(" ".join(x)) for x in [line.split()[0:2] for line in file("testFile",'r').readlines()]]
```

Comment: Hmm, but list comprehension is not very practical if you want to do more complex operations for each line than simply printing a number of columns, isn't it?

Also, is this actually faster than my suggested code?

Comment: Yes. Try using `timeit`. but the difference is not significant as I have tried this for small file content in my case. List comprehensions are always faster as they are done in C (as per many answers read till date).

Answer (score 0):

When you directly iterate over a `file`, the file is read line by line. This helps for huge files but at the penalty of IO, even though if it implements read ahead buffer. AFAIK, internally it uses `seek` and `tell` when iterating.

If you do `read()`, it will read the entire content once but at the cost of memory. In your case you can do `read().split('\n')` or `readlines()` (preferred) and it will be faster than iterating over the file directly.

In addition to the above, please use context managers when dealing with files, so they are closed once done.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html)

Comment: Ran some timing experiments:

    for line in open(f,'r'): 2m23

    for line in open(f,'r').readlines(): 2m23

    C code: 0m19

That's just sad :-(.

Comment: Are you counting the iteration in the `readlines` part? You shouldn't because `readlines` executes only once unlike file iterator itself.

Comment: I was counting some other stuff besides I/O. Less sad now :-).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. csv.reader is implemented in c and should be faster than using pure python.

```
import csv
with open(f, 'rb') as file:
    r = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ')
    for line in r:
        print ' '.join(line[1:3])
```

Comment: Again, this only works if you have a fixed delimiter. The data I work with has both spaces and tabs.

Comment: `split` is written in C also. I'd be very surprised if the `csv` module is faster.

Comment: @niefpaarschoenen sorry, I must have missed that comment. In that case you might want to look at the pandas library. It has a csv reader better suited to large data sets and allows you to use a regex as the deliminator. I haven't had much experience with it though, so I'm not sure if it will be any faster.